# Sharepoint 2013 Apps - Inconsistent error behavior with AppRedirect.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, asp.net-web-api2

As described in the title, the app simply stops working after some time.

The application itself is a simple, one page form that pulls data from a webapi on another webserver by use of the Sharepoint WebProxy and displays that data using knockout.js. The environment and the Sharepoint Server (On-Premise, same domain as my Dev Machine) are configured correctly - supposedly - as described in

[Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)

I can develop, debug in VS, deploy and open the App directly on the Sharepoint Site.

But after a while, when opening the app again without having changed or redeployed anything it stops at this point in the redirect process:

```
https://sharepointurl/_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id=<some-guid>
```

and shows the "This page cannot be displayed" message. The Sharepoint Site still works.

There are no errors in the eventlog. Most of the time I can fix this by restarting the IIS service completely on which the Sharepoint Site resides. But sometimes even that doesnt work.

What could be the problem? Any Idea?

**Update:** The error is not consistent in that it may occur for user A but not for user B and even that can exchange after some time, so that the user B sees the error and user A can use the App.

**Update:** The error only occurs in IE 11 and doesn't happen when using Google Chrome.

<strike>**Update:** It seems as if Sharepoint 2013 Apps **do not work with Internet Explorer 11**, which I was using. As we had other issues with IE 11 and Reporting I downgraded my development machine to IE 10 and now it works.</strike>

**Update:** This had nothing to do with IE 11 either. The error eventually returned.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation would be to have your client use the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer, even on a Windows 7 64-bit Operating System.  Internet Explorer is the ideal browser for Active X and the preferred browser for SharePoint Online for Office 365.

Next I would recommend that your client configure Internet Explorer for SharePoint Online, to review the article detailing this process [click here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2629108).

My last recommendation would be to have them install the latest updates and configure their computers for use with Office 365.  The following links and instructions will detail that process.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Browser Issue. Apparently Sharepoint 2013 Apps do not work with IE 11. 32bit and 64bit did not affect the issue. And we dont use Office 365 at all. Could you add those links and instructions you mentioned in your answer? You seem to have forgotten them.